# MySQL trim data for update

Tags: mysql

I have this table:

```
+--------+------------+---------------------+------+
| id     | product_id | pa_value_name       | oesd |
+--------+------------+---------------------+------+
|      1 |     120972 |                     |    0 |
|      9 |      84147 | 1-2 business days   |    0 |
|   3255 |         12 | 1-3 business days   |    0 |
| 260220 |     124881 | 10-12 business days |    0 |
| 641906 |     147053 | 11-13 business days |    0 |
| 650680 |     139790 | 12-14 business days |    0 |
| 702408 |     112249 | 13-15 business days |    0 |
| 705013 |     223960 | 14-16 business days |    0 |
| 736335 |     124882 | 15-17 business days |    0 |
| 765595 |     106570 | 16-18 business days |    0 |
+--------+------------+---------------------+------+
```

and I want to update *oesd* field by getting the '*to*' date in *pa_value_name* field.

For example:

```
+--------+------------+---------------------+------+
| id     | product_id | pa_value_name       | oesd |
+--------+------------+---------------------+------+
|      9 |      84147 | 1-2 business days   |    2 |
+--------+------------+---------------------+------+
```

In row 2 (id=9): *oesd* must be *2* as it should get '2' from "1-**2** business days" value of *pa_value_name*.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will update `oesd` and convert the value to a number

```
UPDATE the_table SET oesd = CONVERT(SUBSTRING(pa_value_name, LOCATE('-', pa_value_name)+1), decimal);
```

Answer (score 1):

I cannot try it: the idea is to extract the string between **'-'** and **' '**

```
UPDATE your_table SET oesd =
    SUBSTR(pa_value_name, 
           INSTR(pa_value_name,'-') + 1,
           INSTR(pa_value_name,' ') - INSTR(pa_value_name,'-')
          )
```

If oesd is an integer, convert it like this:

```
UPDATE your_table SET oesd =
    CAST(
        SUBSTR(pa_value_name, 
               INSTR(pa_value_name,'-') + 1,
               INSTR(pa_value_name,' ') - INSTR(pa_value_name,'-')
              )
        AS UNSIGNED
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

Extract the "to" date using MySQL's string operations:

- [INSTR](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_instr) eocates the "-" and the space.
- [SUBSTRING](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring) extracts the relevant text.
- [CAST](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast) converts the text to a number